# how to pass file path to my controller for fileupload in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

Im trying to test a method in my controller....
I could give input through browser as im using  REQUEST type to get my values....
Is it possible to Give File path as well along with other key value pairs...
Im trying to give the File path but it is is not being stored...
heres my code....

```
$profilepic = $_FILES['logo']['name'];
$logintype=$_REQUEST['logintype'];

if(!empty($profilepic))
{

    $imagepath = pathinfo($profilepic);
    $pic=date('YmdHis').'.'.$imagepath['extension'];    
    $config['upload_path'] = './user_images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '0';
    $config['max_width']  = '0';
    $config['max_height']  = '0';
    $config['file_name'] = $pic; 
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ($this->upload->do_upload('logo'))
{
  $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
  $profilepicture=$upload_data['file_name'];
  $this->load->model('user_model');             
  $results = $this->user_model->NewSignUp($logintype,$profilepicture);
}           
}
else
{

  $message = array('message'=>"provide values","logintype"=>$logintype,"image"=>"empty image");
  echo json_encode($message);
```

Im trying pass the values as

url: **baseurl/folder/controller/method?logintype=0&logo= C:\Users\php-04\Pictures\tulips.jpg**

and i always get response:

```
{"message":"provide values","logintype":"0","image":"empty image"}
```

Comment: You have an error in your upload, echo upload_errors(); to see what is going wrong. But I don't really understand what you want to achieve ?

Comment: im trying to pass the file location to $profielpic using the url i have mentioned....but it is not being passed....should i change anything

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?

```
$profilepicturePath = $upload_data['full_path'];
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand you, file_path is the location the file is uploaded to and you can only get that after completion. Or what exactly do you mean by "pass the file path using browser url input" ... from input or to input?

Comment: i wanted to pass my local file path as input to the browser so that it calls the controller in server and do the upload...i mean i am not fully aware of file upload...is this possible...

Comment: So you want the location the image came from or where it was stored?

Comment: neither...i just want my file be asigned to $profielpic when i give the browser input as:** baseurl/folder/controller/method?logintype=0&logo= C:\Users\php-04\Pictures\tulips.jpg**...